# Select Screen 0 with xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I have a multi screen :

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 930mm x 530mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

But when i try to do :

```
bussiere@kusanagi [22:03:53] [~/script] [master *]
-> % xrandr --output Screen\ 0 --primary
warning: output Screen 0 not found; ignoring
bussiere@kusanagi [22:04:49] [~/script] [master *]
-> % xrandr --output Screen 0 --primary 
xrandr: unrecognized option '0'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

it doesn't work. How to type correctly Screen 0 for the --primary command of xrandr please ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to set either which screen by *position*, no matter the name, or by *name*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Screen 0" here describes your whole virtual display made of these two outputs:

- **eDP-1-1**:  physical screen plugged to a display-port output
- **HDMI-1-1**: physical screen plugged to a HDMI output

(notice *Screen 0* is 3286 pixel wide, which is 1366 + 1920, the two other outputs horizontal pixels)

I guess you want to use *HDMI-1-1* as primary output, and the following command  will fix that:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --primary
```